# Is there a way to patch/mock geopandas.read_file() to test a function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, patch, geopandas

I developed a function that returns the US state in which a point is, based on latitude and longitude.

**get_state.py:**

```
import geopandas as gpd

def geopandas_read_file(filename):
    return gpd.read_file(filename)

def get_region_info(lat, lon):
    # Create geometry object with (lat, lon) point
    point = g.Point(lat, lon)
    # Read U.S. States Shapefiles
    gdf_states = geopandas_read_file("USA_States.zip")
    # Query State
    states_query = gdf_states[gdf_states.geometry.intersects(point)]
    retun states_query.STATE_ABBR.values[0]
```

And as it is good practice I want to develop tests for this function and add them to the CI/CD pipeline.
The files will not be imported to the repository, that's why I think I need to patch/mock the file.

**test_get_state.py**

```
import get_state as gt
from unittest.mock import patch

f = open("gdf_states_head(5).txt", "r")
print(f.read())

@patch('get_state.geopandas_read_file', side_effect=[f])
def test_happy_path(test_some_file):
    assert gt.get_region_info(-74.50, 40.34) == 'NJ'
    assert test_some_file.call_count == 1
```

The previous version replaced `geopandas_read_file("USA_States.zip")` with `gpd.read_file("USA_States.zip")`, but I decided to change it to how it is because this way I could patch/mock the function.

The problem is that when I run `pytest test_get_state.py` it returns `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'geometry'`

I thought I was going in the right direction but apart from uploading the files to the repository I don't see what else I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
@patch('get_state.gpd')
def test_happy_path(test_some_file):
    test_some_file.read_file.side_effect=[f]
    assert gt.get_region_info(-74.50, 40.34) == 'NJ'
    assert test_some_file.call_count == 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).